# How to use a lookup column's additional field in a workflow?

Tags: 2013, list, lookup-column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

**Background**

I have two lists. One is a list of voltages and their corresponding costs. This is to be used as a lookup for other lists.

```
Voltage           Cost
120               2.50     
240               3.50
...
```

The other list is for people to fill out when they complete a task. This should use a lookup column to pull the price of a voltage from the list above and calculate a final cost.

I fetch it like so:

[image]

And would like to use it in the following way:

```
Voltage       Voltage:Cost     Hours    Final Cost
120           2.50             1        =[Voltage:Cost]+[Hours]*10
240           3.50             2        =[Voltage:Cost]+[Hours]*10
```

**a)** Is it possible to use a lookup column/its additional field in the calculated field? I'm pretty sure not, but hopefully this can change because I can see people needing it for an application like this.

---

**Question**

I know that the [typical workaround](https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/utilize-lookup-column-in-calculated-column-sharepoint-list-libraries/) is creating a workflow that populates a column with the look up item. This works for `Voltage`, but not `Voltage:Cost`.

[image]

See, I have `Voltage:Cost`, and I want to use the workflow to move that to `Power Cost`, so I can calculate `Yearly Cost`. However, in the workflow, I can only move over `Voltage`, not `Voltage:Cost`.

[image]

so **b)** Can I get the additional field of a lookup column, and use that in a workflow?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you only want to display the calculation (and not do any other calculations with it), and on 2010 or 2013??

Comment: 2013. Although I find the JavaScript calculations neat, I'd prefer to actually have the result calculated and stored in the column.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull in the fileds and set the column. **Lookup** and **Lookup:Additional**
[image]

If this doesn't work for you for some reason have you tried to set the field with the data from the source list, rather than using the lookup column?

You'll just need to have some way to connect the two uniquely.
[image]